# What type of wildflower is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I live in Utah and I'm wanting to plant some Utah native plants in my backyard. There is this wildflower everywhere in the mountains of Utah and I really want to know the name. It looks like some sort of Paintbrush (Indian, Wyoming) but I've searched for those and they don't look the same.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As picture doesn't have different close up looks, by its color and looks I think, this is definitely a **species** of [Castilleja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castilleja) ,commonly known as *Indian Paintbrush* or *prairie-fire* :

> Castilleja, commonly known as Indian paintbrush or prairie-fire, **is a genus of about 200 species of annual and perennial herbaceous plants native** to the west of the Americas from Alaska south to the Andes, northern Asia, and one species as far east as the Kola Peninsula in northwestern Russia. These plants are classified in the family Orobanchaceae (following major rearrangements of the order Lamiales starting around 2001; sources which do not follow these reclassifications may place them in the Scrophulariaceae). They are hemiparasitic on the roots of grasses and forbs. The generic name honors Spanish botanist Domingo Castillejo.

It is more likely to be a species of Castilleja called **Castilleja rhexifolia**.
Common names : Alpine paintbrush , Rose(y)  paintbrush.
Family : [Orobanchaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orobanchaceae) (Broomrape Family)

From reference : [Comparison between Castilleja haydenii and Castilleja rhexiifolia](https://www.swcoloradowildflowers.com/Pink%20Enlarged%20Photo%20Pages/castilleja%20haydenii%20&%20rhexifolia.htm) ;

> *Castilleja Rhexiifolia* bract colours are most often hot rose-pink, but they range from subtle magentas to flaming rose to hot iridescent pink.

And on the left and right sides of the question picture have comparatively lower/light pink colour or iridescent pink color and the central flowers are comparatively darker or more magenta when compared to side ones.

Side ones :

[image: light pink/rose colour]

[image: picture (2)]

Central flowers /focused flowers :

[image: central flower]

[image: central flower(2)]

[image: picture (3)]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion, which is not appropriate for answers on this site. ——— Thank you for taking the the [tour], but please also consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.

Comment: @tyersome Thanks a lot for the guidance! I have updated my answer.